# Cron job sometimes fails with error by curl

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, cron, bin

I made a cron job in (Ubuntu 14 Trusty), like this way:

```
sudo crontab-e

then

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    * * * * * curl --silent http://www....cron_script.php >  /dev/null
```

But sometimes, I get this error message to the crown job:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/curl:
/etc/cron.hourly/curl: line 5: bin: command not found
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/curl exited with return code 127
```

Can anybody tell me why? As you can see, it runs every minute, but once a hour I get that error message. Mostly on every hour at XX:54 minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any other crobjobs?

Comment: New error msg:
     /home/gefco/cronjobs/curl: line 4: *: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crontab should'n contain the line:

> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Since you've put the path in the crontab hourly script it executes every hour which make you error show up

Create a script instead and put both lines in there

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
curl --silent http://www....cron_script.php
```

then in crontab just run the script

```
* * * * * my_script.sh >  /dev/null 2>&1
```

Crontab should only contains lines which follows the format:

> m h  dom mon dow   command

Comment: Where should I put the script? In hourly?

Comment: You can put it in your home directory. It doesn't matter as long as you reference it by path in the crontab: * * * * * /home/myname/my_script.sh

Comment: Just make sure the script is executable (chmod +x my_script.sh). Note that I've modified the example to give you a bash script which should work out of the box for you (#!/bin/bash) is needed at the top I think

Comment: If the cronjob still works and you just want to get rid of the errors, add 2>&1 to the end of the command and errors will also be sent to /dev/null and be ignored

Comment: No, not the errors are anoying, the issue itself, that sometimes the cron job does not work at all... and sometimes it does... wtf....

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not able to find command `curl` while running from crontab, so you need to do `which curl` it will give you location of it in your box. Then try to give exact path of that `curl` command **eg-->** `/usr/bin/curl` into cron entry and let me know if this helps you. Also your path details should be added to the user's DOT/BASH profile by which you are running the crontab, then it could work without giving complete path of curl command too.

Comment: Im not a very experienced user, so could you please tell, where should I insert the exact path? Thanks.

Comment: In user's home directory(which you could go by executing only cd command on terminal), then do a ls -la command, it will show you the hidden files too, there you look for either .profile and .bash_profile and try to edit .bash_profile with these path details, have a new session of server then and try to use echo $PATH in it, if it is showing the values it means variables had been picked successfully then.

Comment: i have tried by editing the cron.sh file in my home directory:
/usr/bin/curl --silent http...cronscript.php but like that the cron job did not at all... so, where should I put it?